# Hide a currency Shield UI chart while showing Forex rates

Tags: shieldui

I have a page with a couple of Shield UI Charts, showing different cross currencies forex rates. The type of the charts is line, in case that would make any difference. When I click on a chart’s legend and hide the series it works. However on the next refresh the chart’s data pops up again and the series I just turned off are on again. Is there a workaround this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way I can think of is to add a checkbox in each of the charts containers let’s say an initially non checked checkbox element. Something like that:

```
<input type=checkbox id="Chart_A">Hide Chart</input>
```

Than, when the refresh function is called simply check whether the checkbox is on or off and show the chart accordingly.